# Is it possible to change name of an item in Azure DevOps API?

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

There are a couple of examples online that show how developers use Azure DevOps API to fetch work items or to initiate a build.

However, most of these examples (almost all of them) are related to the metadata stuff that are not directly related to code.

I can't find examples that show how to rename items under source control, how to undo pending changes, how to undelete a deleted item, etc.

Does Azure DevOps API also cover these types of operations to be automated? For example, can I change the name of a given item by not using Visual Studio, and simply by calling an API?

Comment: What kind of items are you thinking of? Source code items? If so, are you using git or tfvs source control in DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change name of an item in Azure DevOps API?

Yes, it is possible.

You could use the REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#rename-a-file), which push changes to the repository:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=5.1
```

The document also provided a sample to [Rename a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#rename-a-file):

Request Body:

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/$(BranchName)",
      "oldObjectId": "9a26002a878f4bb02eae59ffd2f4d881d0dac239"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Renaming tasks.md to activetasks.md",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "rename",
          "sourceServerItem": "TestSample/TestSample/test.txt",
          "item": {
            "path": "TestSample/TestSample/testUpdate.txt"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As the test result:

[image]

Note: The `oldObjectId` in the request body could be the latest commit id on the branch, you can get it by the REST API [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.0&branch={BranchName}&$top=1
```

Hope this helps.